# Does anyone know anything about RAID-K?

Tags: raid

Does anyone know anything about RAID-K I know it is similar to RAID-4.  I know RAID-K is a proprietary version of RAID used by the Kaleidescape, Inc. on the Kaleidescape movie server.

I don't know a lot of RAID and I will be building another PC this time an HTPC and would like to have a few dedicated hard drives for media storage and like what I understand about RAID.  That being said I like the features that RAID-K has and would like something similar. I think will all that being said my best bet would be RAID-5 since I can not find a controller to do RAID-4, but I would like to hear from anyone who may have some suggestions.

Comment: a link to what this 'raid-k' thing is, and what features you specifically need would be helpful

Comment: Sure no problem
http://www.kaleidescape.com/faq/#faq_50150000000M0xeAAC

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia refers to Raid-K as 'Double Parity Raid-4'.

This practically means block level striping (like raid 0) with a dedicated parity disk, and there's a few options

The most common is [raid 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_RAID_levels#RAID_1_.2B_0) , though this is only definately safe when one disk fails at a time.

If you run a dedicated storage box, I'd go for an openindiana system or something else that runs ZFS  with Raid-Z - this should give you striping, mirroring, block level deduplication and redundancy

Comment: Well nothing on the drive will be absolutely critical to protect. Just some high quality movies I acquired and would prefer not have to reacquire them if a drive goes down but would be able to if needed. From what I know of RAID-K is that is has a single Hot Spare drive and if ones fails it automatically rebuilds the array on that spare drive. All I really want is an array with good access speed and some level of redundancy/ability to rebuild the array which is sounds like RAID 10 will do this based on the link you posted am I correct?

Comment: Well, if you want one spare raid 10 or raid 5 would do great.